# Android SDK - is multicastlock working? it does not work when screen is off!

Tags: android, sdk, locking, multicast, listen

I implemented codes for receiving multicast diagram.
My phone can get a diagram when screen is on.

However when screen is off, phone does not get any diagram from subnet.
(PC sends a diagram on subnet for searching phone.)
I though that multicast lock api(WifiManager.MulticastLock) can solve this problem, but it does not work.

How can I listen multicast diagram, phone screen is off ?

Comment: @user512941: What "multicast lock api" are you referring to?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I means that 'WifiManager.MulticastLock' api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need a `WakeLock` and perhaps also a regular `WifiLock`. `WifiManager.MulticastLock` will not keep the device powered on and may not keep the WiFi radio powered on.

Comment: Thank you, however keeping wakelock for a longtime make battery life shorter. Is there any mechanism to use partial wakelock more power efficiently? (maybe turn on partial lock for 10 sec every 30 seconds by alarm)

Comment: @user512941: Polling that frequently will be worse for the battery than leaving it on, I suspect. Moreover, if the CPU shuts down, the WiFi shuts down, and it may take some time to re-establish a WiFi connection. WiFi simply is not a good idea for things when the screen is notionally off, except for short-lived operations (e.g., completing a download that the user started).